# PostgreSQL DB on virtual machine not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I have a virtual machine which i use to have my test database inside. Username and password is postgres and the ip is 192.168.1.255.
Inside my rails app i have a `test.json` file with the following:

```
{
  "db": "postgres://postgres:postgres@192.168.1.255:5432/geoforce_test?search_path=gfv2,public",
  "log_level": 1,
  "db_log": "log/v2-test.db.log"
}
```

However, when i try to run the test (`rspec spec`) I get the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Permission denied (Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError)
    Is the server running on host "192.168.1.255" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your PostgreSQL conf is set to listen to all of your server IPs? By default, postgresql.conf listen only to localhost. Check the entry:

```
listen_addresses
```

And set as

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

Buy the way, you should check your pg_hba.conf also in order to accept connections through your IP.

Comment: how do i check that entry? my pg_hba.conf has my computer IP as trusty

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html . something like: host postgres all 192.168.12.10/32 md5